# Postgres: Import in specific database

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-10

I am trying to import a database in a postgres 10, but I have two instances of postgres with different versions 9.6 and 10 with different ports 5432 and 5433 respectively.
I have created the environment variable PG_HOME with C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10 and the PATH %PGHOME%\bin
When I execute the command:

```
psql -U sigerep sigerep <dbexport.pgsql
```

try to import to the instance with version 9.6, but I need it in 10.

I tried adding the -p 5432 command but it ends up ignoring it:

```
psql: atención: se ignoró argumento extra «-p» en línea de órdenes
psql: atención: se ignoró argumento extra «5433» en línea de órdenes
Contraseña para usuario sigerep:
psql: FATAL:  no existe la base de datos «sigerep»
```

Comment: Please show the exact failing command line.

Comment: The problem I have is when I want to do the import in version 10 of postgres with the command:

  psql -U sigerep sigerep <dbexport.pgsql

  psql: FATAL:  no existe la base de datos «sigerep»


I think the problem is because it is leading by default to the instance with version 9.6

Is there any way I can import it directly in version 10?

Comment: It does not matter which `psql` you are using, both will work. You have to specify the correct port like you tried. What I am asking for is the command line that produced the error. Please add it to the question rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: are u missing the database parameter? -d databasename?
why is sigerep written twice?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you did not create the database "sigerep".
So you have two options:
1. You can import the dump using below command: 
`psql -U sigerep <dbexport.pgsql` 
The above command will import your dump in default database 'postgres'
2. If you want to import dump file in the same database then you will have to create it first.
`psql -c "create database sigerep owner sigerep"` 
After that run the command:
`psql -U sigerep sigerep <dbexport.pgsql`